# Pricing Exotics: Monte-Carlo is too slow?

Tags: monte-carlo, exotics, merton-model

I want to price exotic options under the exponential VG model and Merton's model to compare both models.

To price exotics under Merton's model, I have written the code below. The output is the price of a Call option, Asian, Digital and Up and in Barrier Call option. However, the use of loops leads to a very slow computation. Is there a clever way to not use loops here? In case of the VG model, I can do it but in this case, I do not see it.

```
function [Call,Asian,Digital,UIBP] = ExoticPricingMerton(S0,K,mu,delta,lambda,sigma,r,q,Maturity,H)

ht = 1/252; %trading days
P = 10^3; %Number of simulations
grid = (0:ht:Maturity); 
N = length(grid);

omega = r-q-((1/2)*sigma^2+lambda*(exp(mu+(1/2)*delta^2)-1)); 

S = zeros(P,N);
S(:,1) = S0; 

for i=1:P
    for j=2:length(grid)
        N = poissrnd(lambda*ht);
        J = cumsum([0, normrnd(mu,delta,1,N)]); 
        Z = normrnd(0,1);
        S(i,j) = S(i,j-1)*exp(omega*ht + sigma*sqrt(ht)*Z + J(end));
    end 
end 


%European Call option
A = max(S(:,end)-K,0); 
Call = exp(-r*Maturity)*(1/P)*sum(A); 

%Asian option
A = max(mean(S,2) - K,0);
Asian = exp(-r*Maturity)*(1/P)*sum(A);

%Digital price
A = max(S(:,end) - K, 0)./(S(:,end)-K);
Digital = exp(-r*Maturity)*(1/P)*sum(A);

%Up-and-in out Barrier
A1 = (max(S,[],2)-H)./abs(max(S,[],2)-H);
A2 = max(A1,0);
A = (max(S(:,end)-K,0)).*A2;
UIBP = exp(-r*Maturity)*(1/P)*sum(A); 
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have been solving this issue recently. What caused troubles in my program was the random draws as they turned out to be very slow. I solved it generating random matrix rand(m,n) where m is number of paths and n is number of grid points. For the poisson process u can use poissrnd(lambda,m,n). Then in forloops just select whatever discretization scheme you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am aware that one can generate random numbers in matrix form. However, I'm not sure how to do it for compound Poisson random variables.

Comment: the "J = cumsum([0, normrnd(mu,delta,1,N)]);" does it sum over N draws? You don't seem to save the draws so why not J = sqrt(N) * normrnd(mu,delta,1,1)?

Comment: @MLind the cumsum does indeed sum over the N draws. Thanks for noticing, that is indeed simpler. However, I do not think it will reduce the overall computation time.

Comment: Try it! Michael Mark says random draws are expensive and I divided the number you have to do by N (how large now that one tends to be).

Comment: Ah, I see, N are the jumps, probably not that many then. However, this i a brute force simulation, the most expensive thing you can do. How could it be fast?

Comment: @user39039 Generally, Monte-Carlo Method is time-consuming.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. However, under the VG model, it allows a very fast generation of the sample paths if it is programmed efficiently. Unfortunately, I do not see it for the Merton model. Anyway, it takes about 10 minutes approximately so it is doable. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Pricing barrier options in Monte Carlo is tricky and you're likely to need more than 1000 paths for accurate results.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a wrong tool for the job. Write your Monte Carlo in a faster language (Java would probably suffice, if not than C++ which is standard for such things). Then you will be able to efficiently generate more than 1000 paths. In fact, doing Monte Carlo derivatives pricing with 1000 paths is worthless. Your results are, most probably, very inaccurate. Read a good book on Monte Carlo pricing before venturing further and wasting your time.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, but are there any connectors between Matlab and C++/Java?

Comment: @owejessen yes, you'll likely need to create the wrapper though, but you can for sure do it.

Comment: @will That's good to know, not for myself, but for OP. I live in the R world, and tried to replicate the functions in R / RCPP. It certainly takes a lot of time to run in pure R (as in Matlab), but I'm too dumb to recode in cpp.

Comment: If you want to use cpp in R, you can jsut write a COM interface to the cpp code and call it from R. [Calling cpp from MatLab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.ceval.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop), [from R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/three-ways-to-call-cc-from-r/). You can also create .Net wrappers using [CLI](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppCLINativeDllWrapper-29c32acd) - we use this to call from C# inside an excel-DNA addin. We've used all of these approaches, and they all work nicely.

Comment: It's fairly easy to call Java code from Matlab.

Comment: @quant_dev, I had to use Matlab so there was no other possibility back then. Furthermore, I'm aware that the use of 1000 sample paths is worthless. However, it was already quite slow for 1000 sample paths so imagine how slow it would be for 10^5 sample paths etc. Therefore since I only had one tool, I needed it to be as effective as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using MatLab.

You may consider pre-generating all 1,000 random numbers once before for-loop by exploiting array coding.

Another approach, have you ever tried using Quasi Monte Carlo?

[Generating Quasi-Random Numbers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generating-quasi-random-numbers.html)

QMC ensures faster convergence and MatLab has functions that can generate quasi-random sequence very fast (a billion under a second).

Comment: For 1000 paths, I don't think the difference between pseudo- and quasi-random numbers will be noticeable. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @quant_dev You are right. Quasi will be slower, but it will guarantee better convergence. And I don't think 1000-path will be enough for practical use anyways.